# Good model but bad confusion matrix?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, accuracy, confusion-matrix, kaggle

I am trying to understand the code [here](https://www.kaggle.com/bulentsiyah/dogs-vs-cats-classification-vgg16-fine-tuning).

The output [12] shows that the model accuracy is above 90% even for the validation set, but the confusion matrix in [16] ca not even achieve 50%  accuracy, and it is also on the validation set, so I do not understand this low accuracy on the confusion matrix. I think it may be due to data augmentation, but I would be thankful if someone could explain it to me and tell me how I could then have a confusion matrix in adequacy with the learning curves. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 90%+ accuracy is an evaluation based on Keras' `model.evaluate_generator` method and NOT on validation set, where accuracy is that as shown in confusion matrix

Comment: @NikosM. Thank you for your answer, but how to interpret this ? If we rely on the curves, the model seems good, but if we rely on the confusion matrix the model is bad. How should I interpret these results ?

Comment: The confusion matrix  (and other metrics like precision/recall/etc..) is what counts and all those agree that the model is average

Comment: But if we rely on the confusion matrix, we don't even have 50% of accuracy, so classifying randomly would be better. I don't really understand how this model could be so bad after fine-tuning.

Comment: Me neither, but as it seems this is the case, it is hardly better than random guessing

Comment: I found it strange because nobody discuss it in the comments. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868975/keras-how-to-evaluate-model-accuracy-evaluate-generator-vs-predict-generator/57630536#57630536

I just had to add shuffle = False in the test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe, and the confusion matrix was good